# ogr2ogr convert DXF to GeoJSON with defined geometry

Tags: geojson, ogr, ogr2ogr, dxf

I trie to convert a DXF file into a GeoJSON file with:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'GeoJSON' -sql "SELECT * FROM entities WHERE layer = 'geom_test'" test.json dfxtest.dxf
```

Is it possible to convert only geometries with for example the type point?

Are there documentations or explanations on how to use ogr2ogr with dxf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAL supports two SQL dialects: the default OGR dialect and an alternative SQLite (Spatialite) dialect. Both dialect support selecting geometries by geometry type. Ogrinfo tool is recommended for experiments because by using it the possible troubles with writing the result out can be avoided. If output from ogrinfo is good then the reading side is OK too.

http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html

http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html

Making a selection by geometry type with the OGR SQL dialect:

```
ogrinfo -sql "select * from entities where Layer='New' and OGR_GEOMETRY='POINT'" dxftest.dxf
```

Making a selection by geometry type with the SQLite SQL dialect:

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM entities WHERE layer='New' and GeometryType(geometry)='POINT'" dxftest.dxf
```

Comment: I get an error that the column doesn't exist `ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare(SELECT * from entities WHERE layer ='geom_test' and GeometryType='POINT'):
  no such column: GeometryType`

Comment: Sorry, I sent too early. Should work by using valid SQL `and GeometryType(geometry)='POINT'`

Comment: With GeometryType(geometry) the function doesn't throw an error. But the json file is still nearly empty and doens't contain the features `{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
]
}`

Comment: I found only one simple .dxf file from my computer. Ogrinfo reports only one layer which is "entities". For that file this command gives a good result `ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from entities where GeometryType(geometry)='POINT'" test_dxf.dxf`

Comment: I tried this for my test dxf. When I used WHERE = layer = 'geom_test' all the features are displayed with POINT as the geometry info. When I use WHERE GeometryType(geometry) = 'POINT' it finds nothing. Is probably the dxf broken?

Comment: @user30184 would you please expand on your (original [hit edit]) answer to explain why this answer would work or what it is attempting to do? short answers are susceptible to deletion on this site.

Comment: Hard to say without test data. Meanwhile I tested that layer name + geometry type works for me. I am using Windows, GDAL 2.0-dev and command was `ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from entities where Layer='New' and GeometryType(geometry)='POINT'" oj_dxf.dxf` This file I digitized and saved with OpenJUMP Plus.

Comment: Looks like you do not need to use SQLite dialect but the defauld OGR SQL dialect can be used as well. The syntax is `ogrinfo -sql "select * from entities where Layer='New' and OGR_GEOMETRY='POINT'" oj_dxf.dxf` I will edit my answer to include this option.

Comment: With the selection by geometry type with the OGR SQL dialect it worked for me! Thank you a lot!